# Have any solution for validate gcm token?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a api for register device with the server. In this api, the device must send gcmtoken to the server and server will save it to db. 
My problem is how to server know this gcmtoken has been generate from my app?
Have any suggestion for validate a gcmtoken is generate from my app?

Comment: Server will not know. you have to call a server api to save the GCM token or GCM reg id

Comment: i want to save the GCM token for send google cloud message. And I don't want have anyonce fake gcmtoken and send to my server

Comment: you can set some parameters that only knows by the app. when api call come with that params then only you need to insert it in the DB. you can try kind of header or POST method.

Comment: oh. I can know your parameters by debug http request or decode your app. I will know everything you add to parameters is what. And i can fake api again. I don't want say to author 2.0, because I don't want create account for user.

Comment: You can use Device's IMEI number and store token of its device to the server with the webservice. So one IMEI number should contain only one token at the server.

Answer (score 3):

You can send a test push notification to the newly received token, and check if it fails or not. If you don't want actually send the push notification to the client, use the option `dry_run` in your message option, which won't send the notification, but will check if the token is good. See more details [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json).